# Fetch Date from on-line JSON to Core Data and display-it in a view as NSDate() or other

Tags: json, core-data, swiftui

Not able to display a Json date as Date().
Here are my files:

ListingModel.swift

```swift
struct ListingModel:  Hashable, Decodable, Encodable, Identifiable {
    var id : Int
    var title : String
    var expires: Date
    }
```

Core data Entity for Listing:

Attribute: expires

Type: Date

Optional: Yes

Use Scalar Type: Yes

Than save it at fetch request:

```swift
func saveData(contex: NSManagedObjectContext) {
            
           
            listings.forEach() { (data) in
            
             let entity = Listing(context: contex)
                        entity.id = Int64(data.id)
                        entity.title = data.title
                        entity.expires = data.expires
```

// i get the error here: Cannot assign value of type 'Date' to type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')

```
              do{

                try contex.save()

                print("success")
            }
            catch{
     print(error.localizedDescription)
                let nserror = error as NSError
                  NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
}
```

From Json the date type is like this:

expires : "2102-12-21"

I want to use this date in a view like this:

if expire > Today {

listing.delete() (from core data)

or

Text("Expired")

}

Answer (score 0):

The attribute type

> Use Scalar Type: Yes

and the error

> Cannot assign value of type 'Date' to type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')

clearly indicate that the attribute is treated as `TimeInterval` (aka `Double`) rather than  as `Date`.

Uncheck the checkbox `Use Scalar Type`.

Comment: Doing this triger error at Persistant controller: hread 1: Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model." UserInfo={destinationModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x6000018a40f0>) isEditable 0, entities {

Comment: Of course you get this error if you have already records in your database. Migrate the data by creating a new version of the Core Data model. Or keep the old model and convert `Date` to `TimeInterval` in the lines where the first error occurs.

Comment: Or given you are still in development and don’t have your app live then just delete your app from your test device / simulator and then rebuild.